# Solr indexing for large rows from database

Tags: solr, solrj, solrcloud

I am using solr 8.2 and jdk 11.0.4. I was using solr 7.5 and jdk 11.0.4 and it suddenly stopped working. So i converted to solr 8.2.0. Now for small data full indexing is working. I tried around 2000 rows. When i tried 7 to lakhs records it stops the solr working. But its status showing 
Active: active(exited) since Mon 2019-08-26 ; 54 min ago 
But its not responding when i tried from browser and terminal 
sudo curl "http://localhost:8983/solr/article/select?q=how" .

I have updated the solr version and increased 
 JAVA_MEM_OPTS=("-Xms10G" "-Xmx10G")
server :ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS
i removed XX:+UseLargePages'  from GC tune

I had 20 cores. Now i removed all cores and kept only two cores. If i keep all the cores it stops responding after sometime. If i keep only one core for long time then its running without interuption. when i start indexing it will stop responding.
G1 Evacuation Pause count:11 , time :97.25%
Metadata GC Threshold:  2 ,time: 0.71%

JAVA_MEM_OPTS=("-Xms10G" "-Xmx10G")
if [ -z ${GC_TUNE+x} ]; then
      GC_TUNE=('-XX:+UseG1GC' \  '-XX:+PerfDisableSharedMem' \   '-XX:+ParallelRefProcEnabled' \ '-XX:MaxGCPauseMillis=250' \ '-XX:+UseLargePages' \ '-XX:+AlwaysPreTouch')  else  GC_TUNE=($GC_TUNE)   fi

Solr shouldn't stop when  i am indexing. Now its not responding but status showing since 56 min started
What could be the cause of this. Anything wrong in the above configuration

Comment: How are you indexing? How much pressurs? Single node or a cluster? What does a thread dump for Solr say when it's locked? https://blog.fastthread.io/2016/06/06/how-to-take-thread-dumps-7-options/

Comment: mysql data full  import. single node.

Comment: Threddump file "G1 Young RemSet Sampling" os_prio=0 cpu=765.61ms elapsed=2605.65s tid=0x00007ff94ce37800 nid=0x4447 runnable  
"VM Periodic Task Thread" os_prio=0 cpu=1527.90ms elapsed=2605.41s tid=0x00007ff94cf30000 nid=0x4464 waiting on condition  

JNI global refs: 27, weak refs: 0

Comment: I recommend moving your indexing process out from Solr itself - in particular when the built-in indexing process becomes an issue, so instead of using DIH write a small script that fetches the data, processes it and inserts it into Solr through the regular endpoints. In this case it seems like your VM gets stuck while processing its garbage collection. Try upgrading your JVM or use a different garbage collector.

Comment: Thanks. any version degrade will solve the problem. Even though not indexing after sometime solr is locked if i add all my cores. is It GC related issues or any other configuration issue. Even i allocated more space still its happening. server ram size is 32 gb.  memory -Xms10G" "-Xmx10G

Comment: I'd try switching to a different GC in the JVM and see if that solves it.

Comment: i swithed gc '-XX:NewRatio=3' \       '-XX:SurvivorRatio=4' \         '-XX:TargetSurvivorRatio=90' \         '-XX:MaxTenuringThreshold=8' \     
        '-XX:ConcGCThreads=4' '-XX:ParallelGCThreads=4' \         '-XX:+CMSScavengeBeforeRemark' \         '-XX:PretenureSizeThreshold=64m' \
        '-XX:+UseCMSInitiatingOccupancyOnly' \         '-XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=50' \         '-XX:CMSMaxAbortablePrecleanTime=6000' \         '-XX:+CMSParallelRemarkEnabled' \      '-XX:+ParallelRefProcEnabled' \
        '-XX:-OmitStackTraceInFastThrow' but there is no change exepected output.

Comment: Neither of those parameters change the GC. Remove the `+UseG1GC` flag and replace with [another option for testing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/vm/gctuning/collectors.html)

Comment: You've tagged this with `solrj`, but it doesn't sound like you're using it at all. Maybe you should, or use the suggestion of a simple script to index data. Either solution is basically accomplishes the same thing and gives you more control over the indexing process.